# Create a Schedule task that run a access file

Tags: ms-access, scheduled-tasks

Im confusing how the Schedule task can run a Microsoft Access module.

I want to have a server with the access Database and forms (accdb file) with it.
In this serve there isnt microsoft access installed only the accdb file. The users access the file by remote.

i created a module that send emails, im i wat to know if its possible to create any ST that access the access file without the serve have the Microsoft Access installed.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Access installed on the machine where the scheduled task runs, you will not be able to run the procedure stored in a VBA module in your ACCDB file.

Adapt your VBA procedure to VBScript and run the VBScript file as a scheduled task.

Comment: And do i access to database in accdb file from VB Script? if i dont have the access installed

Comment: VBScript can connect to the ACCDB using ADO, ODBC, or with COM automation of a DAO DBEngine object.

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that you must have the ACE driver to connect to an ACCDB file.  And if your code is running in 32-bit mode, you need the 32-driver ... or 64-bit driver for 64-bit mode.  If you run into this issue, you can find many SO questions and answers about it.